# grep works fine in command line but returns nothing in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I'm trying to write a small script to get me list of files that match certain criteria into a file.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www_data/patch/
grep --include=\*.{php,ini,conf,sh} -ril -P "'([\d\w\-\_\.]+)(@domain.com)'" "/var/www_data/something/" 2>&1 > mails
```

The `grep` line works perfectly in command line but if I launch it via script, resulting file will have size of 0 bytes. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have permission to write in this directory?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, of course. Thing is, even if comment out `2>&1 > mails` part, it won't output anything into terminal

Comment: Your script contains bashisms (such as the brace expansion `{php,ini,conf,sh}`) but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. Are you sure `/bin/sh` is a bash shell on your system - it is often a symlink to a simpler shell such as `dash`.

Comment: @steeldriver oh yeah, indeed , it was supposed to be #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 4):

Found my own mistake. It was supposed to be `#!/bin/bash`. Thanks to @steeldriver for the tip

Comment: Interesting definition of "found my own mistake" :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable shell expansion within a script you have to pass a command line option to bash, this can be done in the script itself:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -B   #enables expansion
set -X   #enables debugging
```

With the first option everything will be passed to the shell as if it were written in the command line, the second option will generate a lot of output, quite useful to see what happens but you surely want to disable it once your script is working properly.